# Get numerical patterns from a line using sed/grep

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a stream of lines as follows

```
iter: 0 ival: 0, fcost =               0
iter: 0 ival: 1, fcost =               1
iter: 0 ival: 2, fcost =    0.7115281224
iter: 1 ival: 3, fcost =    0.3990854323
iter: 2 ival: 4, fcost =    0.1486154944
iter: 3 ival: 5, fcost =    0.1353816539
iter: 4 ival: 6, fcost =    0.1013548374
iter: 5 ival: 7, fcost =    0.1856721342
```

I want to get comma or space separated numerical values from this stream of lines. 
Something like this

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 2 0.7115281224
1 3 0.3990854323
2 4 0.1486154944
3 5 0.1353816539
4 6 0.1013548374
5 7 0.1856721342
5 8 0.08961682022
6 9 0.08508076519
```

Is there a way I can do it using grep or sed?

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure the lines will always follow this pattern, you can use awk to select the appropriate columns, given the correct delimiters (in this case space or comma):

`awk -F '[, ]+' '{print $2"\t"$4"\t"$7}' file.txt`

The -F option accepts a regex, so you can choose better delimiters in the future if you'd like to.

Here's the output:

```
$ cat file.txt 
iter: 0 ival: 0, fcost =               0
iter: 0 ival: 1, fcost =               1
iter: 0 ival: 2, fcost =    0.7115281224
iter: 1 ival: 3, fcost =    0.3990854323
iter: 2 ival: 4, fcost =    0.1486154944
iter: 3 ival: 5, fcost =    0.1353816539
iter: 4 ival: 6, fcost =    0.1013548374
iter: 5 ival: 7, fcost =    0.1856721342
$ awk -F '[, ]+' '{print $2"\t"$4"\t"$7}' file.txt 
0   0   0
0   1   1
0   2   0.7115281224
1   3   0.3990854323
2   4   0.1486154944
3   5   0.1353816539
4   6   0.1013548374
5   7   0.1856721342
```

Edit:
As pointed out in the comments, when printing the result you may not want the separator between numbers to be a tab character, so you may choose other character instead of "\t" on the example above. You can also use something like:

`awk -F '[, ]+' '{print $2,$4,$7}' file.txt`

Which will use a [single space](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_7.html) as a separator:

> They are output, separated by single spaces, followed by a newline.

Other option could be using [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html#Printf), for more complex combinations.

Comment: Thank you. However, I also found a way of doing so using sed.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, but mind the `\t` in case you want to only use a single space separator

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the way how can we do it. Thanks to [this answer](http://www.example.com/). Basically we can do this

```
sed 's/[^[0-9\.\-]]*/ /g;s/ \+/ /g;s/^ \+\| \+$//g' filename
```

where
`s/[^[0-9\.\-]]*/ /g` : replaces all non-numerical values by spaces
`s/ \+/ /g` : replaces all whitespaces by a single whitespace
`s/^ \+\| \+$//g` : replaces all preceding and trailing whitespaces

Comment: Within `[]`, you don't have to escape anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [tr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) to delete the complementary set of characters that aren't digits, a dot or a newline. A second pipeline to `tr` to squeeze the multiple spaces to one can clean-up the output.

```
echo "iter: 5 ival: 7, fcost =    0.1856721342"|tr -cd " .0123456789\n"|tr -s " "
5 7 0.1856721342
```